# Error wile debugging (signature buffer too small)

Tags: plsql, oracle-9i, debugging

I'm trying to debug a package in SQL Developer, but I keep getting error:

```
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [15419], [severe error during PL/SQL execution], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-06544: PL/SQL: internal error, arguments: [pbjrms - signature buffer too small], [38], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-06553: PLS-801: internal error [pbjrms - signature buffer too small]
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.DISCONNECT()
Closed Connection
```

Package compiled without errors. Anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a known bug, fixed in 9.2.0.5.
This is the note on Oracle Support that describes this error:

**Bug 2829071 - PLS-801/OERI:[15419] when debugging PLSQL from JDWP debugger (Doc ID 2829071.8)**